# Create a completely blank page only for adding Script Editor Web Part, around 30 of them

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, master-page, custom-masterpage

I want to create a **blank page** which I can edit and add **Script Editor Web Parts** according to the requirement. Tried creating a custom master page for a custom page layout but something didn't work right and it kept saying, 'File not found'.

Tried creating and using Minimal Master Page as well. That also didn't work.

Tried the approach mentioned in the following link as well but of no use. :(

[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/22b50a46-8b5b-4760-9017-efcce736da5e/how-to-create-a-completely-blank-page-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)

Comment: Can you be more specific about "didn't work"? Examples of your master pages and layouts would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with master pages and layouts if all you are trying to do is create web part pages and add a script editor.  All you need to do is use a browser and navigate to your Site Pages library(s), create a page, edit the page and add the script web part, add your script and save.